# What is our stance on questions asking whether traveling to some area is safe?

Tags: discussion, scope

What is our stance on questions asking whether traveling to some area is safe? Are they on-topic or off-topic?

Example of closed question:

- [Is it safe for a foreigner to travel to Russia these days?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/175521/1810)

Examples of opened question:

- [How dangerous is the 'La Boca' neighborhood of Buenos Aires?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13279/1810)
- [What areas in London, Manchester, and Edinburgh should I avoid?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/175561/1810)

Answer (score 8):

In itself it is acceptable to ask about safety of an area, but the actual wording of said question will make the difference, as well as the mood of people voting to keep open or close of course.

The question needs to be such that it invites facts rather than opinions, the area it is about needs to be either alike as a whole, in case of the Russia question it is about the government and as such the whole of the country, or limited in size so the area is homogene enough for a single answer.

And in the cases of the recent questions you linked to, a lot of flagging of question, answers and comments resulted, mostly based on rude or insulting. Which seems the norm for this kind of questions, as they often invite heated discussions or 'that does not happen in my country' reactions.

So even though acceptable as a subject most safety questions will get close votes because of the nature of the subject and edits to make them fit the site better are very common.

Comment: It is important for OP to specify what they mean by safety and what their concerns are.

Comment: Thanks, [how to invite facts rather than opinions when asking whether traveling to some area is safe?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8675/1810)