# How to invite facts rather than opinions when asking whether traveling to some area is safe?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

When asking [What is our stance on questions asking whether traveling to some area is safe?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8367/1810) I was told:

> The question needs to be such that it invites facts rather than opinions

How to invite facts rather than opinions when asking whether traveling to some area is safe?

I didn't see any clear patterns when comparing open questions (e.g., [How dangerous is the 'La Boca' neighborhood of Buenos Aires?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13279/1810) and [What areas in London, Manchester, and Edinburgh should I avoid?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/175561/1810)) against closed questions (e.g., [How safe is the Dominican Republic currently?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/188270/1810)).